# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated using robot framework

Tags: python, html, selenium, robotframework

The issue that I am having is with a dropdown.

When I am executing the script, I am getting the following error:ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

When I Look at the html I see that there is an ID availble for the dropdown 'IsActive', however when I inspect the element, another id is present 'IsActive_Chosen'

[image]

How do I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ActionChains` to overcome your issue:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
selectElement=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "form-control chosen-select")))
ActionChains(drivers).move_to_element(selectElement).click().perform()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```